# maven buildでbatファイルを実行したい

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-boot, maven

maven buildを実施した際に、phaseが「prepare-package」の時にあるbatファイルを実行したいのですが、その様なことは可能でしょうか。
pom.xmlのexecutionタグ内に定義できないかなと考えているのですが...
WEB上で検索してもなかなかその様な情報を見つけることができなかったため、質問しました。
初歩的な質問かもしれません...検索キーワードだけでもご教示頂けると幸いです。

- OS：Windows7
- 開発環境：Eclipse
- 言語：Java
- フレームワーク：Spring Boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html)を導入すればできました。